# Simple way to convert a string to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

What is the simplest way to convert a string of keyword=values to a dictionary, for example the following string:

```
name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"
```

to the following python dictionary:

```
{'name':'John Smith', 'age':34, 'height':173.2, 'location':'US', 'avatar':':,=)'}
```

The 'avatar' key is just to show that the strings can contain = and , so a simple 'split' won't do. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
# get all the items
matches = re.findall(r'\w+=".+?"', s) + re.findall(r'\w+=[\d.]+',s)

# partition each match at '='
matches = [m.group().split('=', 1) for m in matches]

# use results to make a dict
d = dict(matches)
```

Comment: This works--just add routines to convert the final values into strings/ints etc, and perhaps strip out unwanted double quotes included in the values.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I knew regular expressions would be the answer, just never managed to learn how to use them efficiently!

Comment: Trust me friend, they're worth the effort. Find a good interactive regex tester (like redemo.py) and get your feet wet!

Comment: Note that there are some strings which will cause the above regexp solution to do strange things, eg `avatar="p=0"`, or worse `avatar="age=123"`.  You'll need a parser based solution if those worry you.

BTW I don't know if you have any control over the input format, but JSON is very close to the input format above and there are modules in nearly every language to parse it.  http://json.org/

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: since the `csv` module doesn't deal as desired with quotes *inside* fields, it takes a bit more work to implement this functionality:

```
import re
quoted = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"')

class QuoteSaver(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.saver = dict()
    self.reverser = dict()

  def preserve(self, mo):
    s = mo.group()
    if s not in self.saver:
      self.saver[s] = '"%d"' % len(self.saver)
      self.reverser[self.saver[s]] = s
    return self.saver[s]

  def expand(self, mo):
    return self.reverser[mo.group()]

x = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"'

qs = QuoteSaver()
y = quoted.sub(qs.preserve, x)
kvs_strings = y.split(',')
kvs_pairs = [kv.split('=') for kv in kvs_strings]
kvs_restored = [(k, quoted.sub(qs.expand, v)) for k, v in kvs_pairs]

def converter(v):
  if v.startswith('"'): return v.strip('"')
  try: return int(v)
  except ValueError: return float(v)

thedict = dict((k.strip(), converter(v)) for k, v in kvs_restored)
for k in thedict:
  print "%-8s %s" % (k, thedict[k])
print thedict
```

I'm emitting `thedict` twice to show exactly how and why it differs from the required result; the output is:

```
age      34
location US
name     John Smith
avatar   :,=)
height   173.2
{'age': 34, 'location': 'US', 'name': 'John Smith', 'avatar': ':,=)',
 'height': 173.19999999999999}
```

As you see, the output for the floating point value is as requested when directly emitted with `print`, but it isn't and **cannot** be (since there *IS* no floating point value that would display `173.2` in such a case!-) when the `print` is applied to the whole `dict` (because that inevitably uses `repr` on the keys and values -- and the `repr` of `173.2` has that form, given the usual issues about how floating point values are stored in binary, not in decimal, etc, etc).  You might define a `dict` subclass which overrides `__str__` to specialcase floating-point values, I guess, if that's indeed a requirement.

But, I hope this distraction doesn't interfere with the core idea -- as long as the doublequotes are properly balanced (and there are no doublequotes-inside-doublequotes), this code does perform the required task of preserving "special characters" (commas and equal signs, in this case) from being taken in their normal sense when they're inside double quotes, even if the double quotes start *inside* a "field" rather than at the beginning of the field (`csv` only deals with the latter condition).  Insert a few intermediate prints if the way the code works is not obvious -- first it changes all "double quoted fields" into a specially simple form (`"0"`, `"1"` and so on), while separately recording what the actual contents corresponding to those simple forms are; at the end, the simple forms are changed back into the original contents.  Double-quote stripping (for strings) and transformation of the unquoted strings into integers or floats is finally handled by the simple `converter` function.

Comment: As for Managu's similar solution, this doesn't work if the string on the right contains commas (which they do in the case I'm working with).

Comment: You're right == csv doesn't understand quotes "in the middle" of fields.  Let me figure out something else and fix my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a lazy way of doing this.

```
test_string = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"'
eval("dict({})".format(test_string))
```

> {'age': 34, 'location': 'US', 'avatar': ':,=)', 'name': 'John Smith', 'height': 173.2}

Hope this helps someone !

Comment: If possible, the use of `eval` should be avoided. In the real world, `test_string` may be user input, and a malicious user might abuse this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more verbose approach to the problem using pyparsing.  Note the parse actions
which do the automatic conversion of types from strings to ints or floats.  Also, the
QuotedString class implicitly strips the quotation marks from the quoted value.  Finally,
the Dict class takes each 'key = val' group in the comma-delimited list, and assigns 
results names using the key and value tokens.

```
from pyparsing import *

key = Word(alphas)
EQ = Suppress('=')
real = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
integer = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
qs = QuotedString('"')
value = real | integer | qs

dictstring = Dict(delimitedList(Group(key + EQ + value)))
```

Now to parse your original text string, storing the results in dd.  Pyparsing returns an 
object of type ParseResults, but this class has many dict-like features (support for keys(), 
items(), in, etc.), or can emit a true Python dict by calling asDict().  Calling dump() 
shows all of the tokens in the original parsed list, plus all of the named items.  The last
two examples show how to access named items within a ParseResults as if they were attributes of
a Python object.

```
text = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"'
dd = dictstring.parseString(text)
print dd.keys()
print dd.items()
print dd.dump()
print dd.asDict()
print dd.name
print dd.avatar
```

Prints:

```
['age', 'location', 'name', 'avatar', 'height']
[('age', 34), ('location', 'US'), ('name', 'John Smith'), ('avatar', ':,=)'), ('height', 173.19999999999999)]
[['name', 'John Smith'], ['age', 34], ['height', 173.19999999999999], ['location', 'US'], ['avatar', ':,=)']]
- age: 34
- avatar: :,=)
- height: 173.2
- location: US
- name: John Smith
{'age': 34, 'height': 173.19999999999999, 'location': 'US', 'avatar': ':,=)', 'name': 'John Smith'}
John Smith
:,=)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code produces the correct behavior, but is just a bit long! I've added a space in the avatar to show that it deals well with commas and spaces and equal signs inside the string. Any suggestions to shorten it?

```
import hashlib

string = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":, =)"'

strings = {}

def simplify(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except:
        return float(value)

while True:
    try:
        p1 = string.index('"')
        p2 = string.index('"',p1+1)
        substring = string[p1+1:p2]
        key = hashlib.md5(substring).hexdigest()
        strings[key] = substring
        string = string[:p1] + key + string[p2+1:]
    except:
        break

d = {}    
for pair in string.split(', '):
    key, value = pair.split('=')
    if value in strings:
        d[key] = strings[value]
    else:
        d[key] = simplify(value)

print d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a approach with `eval`, I considered it is as unreliable though, but its works for your example.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s='name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"'
>>>
>>> eval("{"+re.sub('(\w+)=("[^"]+"|[\d.]+)','"\\1":\\2',s)+"}")
{'age': 34, 'location': 'US', 'name': 'John Smith', 'avatar': ':,=)', 'height': 173.19999999999999}
>>>
```

**Update:**

Better use the one pointed by Chris Lutz in the comment, I believe Its more reliable, because even there is (single/double) quotes in dict values, it might works.

Comment: If you're going to use `eval` why not just do `eval("dict(" + s + ")")` ? We don't need to do any regex substitutions here when Python already supports this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat more robust version of the regexp solution:

```
import re

keyval_re = re.compile(r'''
   \s*                                  # Leading whitespace is ok.
   (?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(                 # Search for a key followed by..
       (?P<str>"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')|     #   a quoted string; or
       (?P<float>\d+\.\d+)|             #   a float; or
       (?P<int>\d+)                     #   an int.
   )\s*,?\s*                            # Handle comma & trailing whitespace.
   |(?P<garbage>.+)                     # Complain if we get anything else!
   ''', re.VERBOSE)

def handle_keyval(match):
    if match.group('garbage'):
        raise ValueError("Parse error: unable to parse: %r" %
                         match.group('garbage'))
    key = match.group('key')
    if match.group('str') is not None:
        return (key, match.group('str')[1:-1]) # strip quotes
    elif match.group('float') is not None:
        return (key, float(match.group('float')))
    elif match.group('int') is not None:
        return (key, int(match.group('int')))
```

It automatically converts floats & ints to the right type; handles single and double quotes; handles extraneous whitespace in various locations; and complains if a badly formatted string is supplied

```
>>> s='name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"'
>>> print dict(handle_keyval(m) for m in keyval_re.finditer(s))
{'age': 34, 'location': 'US', 'name': 'John Smith', 'avatar': ':,=)', 'height': 173.19999999999999}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set maxsplit=1, for instance the following should work.

```
string = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":, =)"'
newDict = dict(map( lambda(z): z.split("=",1), string.split(", ") ))
```

Edit (see comment):

I didn't notice that ", " was a value under avatar, the best approach would be to escape ", " wherever you are generating data. Even better would be something like JSON ;). However, as an alternative to regexp, you could try using shlex, which I think produces cleaner looking code.

```
import shlex

string = 'name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":, =)"'
lex = shlex.shlex ( string ) 
lex.whitespace += "," # Default whitespace doesn't include commas
lex.wordchars += "."  # Word char should include . to catch decimal 
words = [ x for x in iter( lex.get_token, '' ) ]
newDict = dict ( zip( words[0::3], words[2::3]) )
```

Comment: its give me this `{'': ')"', 'name': '"John Smith"', 'age': '34', 'height': '173.2', 'location': '"US"', 'avatar': '":'}`

Answer (score 0):

do it step by step

```
d={}
mystring='name="John Smith", age=34, height=173.2, location="US", avatar=":,=)"';
s = mystring.split(", ")
for item in s:
    i=item.split("=",1)
    d[i[0]]=i[-1]
print d
```

Answer (score -2):

Always comma separated?  Use the CSV module to split the line into parts (not checked):

```
import csv
import cStringIO

parts=csv.reader(cStringIO.StringIO(<string to parse>)).next()
```

Comment: This does not work in the case where a string on the right hand side contains a comma, e.g. in the 'avatar' case above. A comma will only be present on the right hand side if it is inside quotes though, so maybe this can be taken into account?

Comment: CSV *should* take it into account if you use the right dialect.