# String containing list and other data types to dictionary without changing the data type in python

Tags: python

I have one string as below:

```
key_val = "count=2, name=['hello', 'hi'], word='Dial::100', roll=12"
```

I need to get the dictionary from the string as below:

```
d_key_val = {'count'=2, 'name'=['hello', 'hi'], 'word'='Dial::100', 'roll'=12}
```

I tried with the following:

```
regx = r'(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\[.+?\]|\d+|\S+)'
r_key_val = re_findall(regx, key_val)
for key, value in r_key_val:
        d_key_val[key] = value
```

But it is storing values as all string:

```
d_key_val = {'count'='2', 'name'="['hello', 'hi']", 'word'="'Dial::100'", 'roll'='12'}
```

Is there any way or regex to store the values as same data type as it has in string?

Comment: Related: [Simple way to convert a string to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814400/simple-way-to-convert-a-string-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that the data is "safe", you could [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) it as the parameters to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> key_val = "count=2, name=['hello', 'hi'], word='Dial::100', roll=12"
>>> eval("dict(%s)" % key_val)
{'count': 2, 'name': ['hello', 'hi'], 'roll': 12, 'word': 'Dial::100'}
```

If you are *not* sure, better don't use `eval`, though.

---

Alternatively, you could use your regex and use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the `value`:

```
>>> regx = r'(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\[.+?\]|\d+|\S+)'
>>> {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k, v in re.findall(regx, key_val)}
{'count': 2, 'name': ['hello', 'hi'], 'roll': 12, 'word': ('Dial::100',)}
```

(Note: I did not check your regex in detail.) You *could* also try to apply `ast.literal_eval` to the entire expression, instead of the less safe `eval`, but this would require some preprocessing, e.g. replacing `=` with `:` and adding quotes to the keys, that might not work well with e.g. string values containing those symbols.

Answer (score 0):

`regex` cannot do that, but you can! You can write a function like the following that takes the `values` `regex` writes out and converts them to the appropriate type.

```
def type_converter(v):
    if v[0] == '[' and v[-1] == ']':
        v = v.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
        return [type_converter(x) for x in v.split(',')]
    try:
        v = int(v)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            v = float(v)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    finally:
        return v
```

To add this to your code, simply do:

```
regx = r'(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>\[.+?\]|\d+|\S+)'
r_key_val = re_findall(regx, key_val)
for key, value in r_key_val:
    d_key_val[key] = type_converter(value)  # <- this
```

---

Example:

```
lst = ['2', '1.2' ,'foo', '[1, 2]']
print([type(type_converter(x)) for x in lst ])  
# [<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'list'>]
```

Note that the order in which the `try`-blocks are written is very important since `float('1')` does not raise any Errors but the correct type is `int`!

Comment: More difficult for the `list` part, though. Maybe use `ast.literal_eval` instead?

Comment: @tobias_k I noticed that later but I updated the fuction to a recursive one to handle that. At the end of the day, `ast.literal_eval` or some fancy `json` command might be much handier.