# Django how to query with condition in a string

Tags: django

I have the following query:

`list = catalog['model'].objects.all().values(*catalog['id_label']).order_by('name')`

and I have the following variable: `filter='state=1'`

How can I change `all()` for `filter()`, and make **django** to use the content of variable `filter` as input for `filter()`?

Comment: you should be able to use filter(state=1) instead of all() and it should be correct, what is the problem ?

Comment: That `state=1` is the current value of `filter`, but it can change in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your **string** to  **dictionary** and then use that as the input for the `filter`:

```
filter_dict = dict([filter.split('=')])


list = catalog['model'].objects.filter(**filter_dict).values(*catalog['id_label']).order_by('name')
```

or if you have more than one `key=value` pair in your `filter` variable, you can use regex to convert them to dict, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814489/9733868).